# Call more than one function 'onClick'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, onclick

Here is my situation:

```
<button onClick={this.changeTimerStatus.bind(this)}>makeTimerCliccable</button>

<button onClick={this.state.hasBeenFinished ? this.confirmHandler : (this.state.hasDest == false || this.state.hasDest == undefined ? this.takeTaskHandler : this.finishHandler)}>
```

I have two buttons, but I'd like to have just the second one. Also, I'd like to execute `this.changeTimerStatus.bind(this)` (the function on the first button) together with `this.confirmHandler` or `this.takeTaskHandler` when they're running. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you. Also here is a sandbox so you can see it in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-bassi-2lwbu

```
    <button
      onClick={
        this.state.hasBeenFinished
          ? () => {
              this.changeTimerStatus();
              this.confirmHandler();
            }
          : !this.state.hasDest
          ? () => {
              this.changeTimerStatus();
              this.takeTaskHandler();
            }
          : this.finishHandler
      }
    >
       Click
    </button>
```

As fellow posters have mentioned, you can move all this logic into a single event-handler like so and pair it with the event-listener

```
handleClick = () => {
   this.state.hasBeenFinished
       ? () => {
           this.changeTimerStatus();
           this.confirmHandler();
         }
       : !this.state.hasDest
       ? () => {
           this.changeTimerStatus();
           this.takeTaskHandler();
          }
       : this.finishHandler
}
```

Then in the button:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
```

The benefits of doing this are:

1. Prevents unnecessary re-renders caused by using anonymous
   functions as event-handlers during render.
2. Cleans up your mark-up so its easier to read the logic behind
   your component.

Comment: you can replace `this.state.hasDest == false || this.state.hasDest == undefined` by `!this.state.hasDest`

Comment: not good practice (avoid new function ref creation in render - forces unnecessary rerendering), not optimal (logic calculation on every render vs only one calculation on demand - within binded handler)

Answer (score 0):

The answer that is accepted here will work, but that is not a good practice to use any logic inside your markup (in this case jsx). I would suggest to create one handler,

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        // Whatever you store in the state
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
    }

    clickHandler() {
        // this.state
        // ...logic can go here
        // it should be the same logic as it is in the accepted answer
    }

    render() {
         return (
              <button type="button" onClick={ this.clickHandler }>
                  BUTTON
              </button>
         );
    }
}
```